# ¿Como moverme por capas con Jquery o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hay una funcion en Jquery que me permite segun un id o clase, subir una o bajar una

Ejemplo

```
<div id="capa1">
     <div id="buscado">
          <label>Por encontrar</label>
     </div>
     <div id="capa2">
          <label id="inicio">Busquemos</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Necesito moverme desde "Busquemos" a "Por encontrar", con javascript o Jquery

Ejemplo

```
$(#inicio).subir().subir().buscar('buscado');
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: `$(#inicio).parent().parent().find('#buscado');`

Comment: Vale compañere <3

Comment: @alanfcm eso es la respuesta?

Comment: Si @gbianchi ..

Comment: Y si lo pones como respuesta @alanfcm? con un poquito de contexto (aunque no sea mucho) sirve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes el `label` con `id=inicio` en una variable, entonces usas la funcion `parent()` para obtener el contenedor padre.  En este caso lo tienes que usar 2 veces para alcanzar el contenedor `capa1`.  Luego para buscar otro elemento dentro utilizas la funcion `find()`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
var inicio = $('#inicio');
var buscado = $(inicio).parent().parent().find('#buscado');
console.log(buscado.text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="capa1">
     <div id="buscado">
          <label>Por encontrar</label>
     </div>
     <div id="capa2">
          <label id="inicio">Busquemos</label>
     </div>
</div>
```